# lock var lib folder

Tags: environment-variables, lock

Hi I installed a program ant between install it disconnected from internet and when I want to install program i can not and give this error what shoud I do?

Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lock file and try again

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

then

```
apt-get install <package-name>
```